# Convert .zip file into byte array and re-create .zip from byte array

Tags: c#, .net, zip

I have converted a .zip file into a byte[], and now I am trying to convert the byte[] back to the original .zip file. I am running out of the options that I have tried. Anyone give me a pointer how can I achieve this?

Comment: You know that reading thing you did to turn the file into a byte array?  Do the opposite of that.

Comment: File.WriteAllBytes(pathToSave)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the [System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
using (ZipArchive zip = ZipFile.Open("test.zip", ZipArchiveMode.Create))
{
    var entry = zip.CreateEntry("File Name.txt");
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(entry.Open()))
    {
        sw.Write("Some Text");  
    }
}

using (ZipArchive zip = ZipFile.Open("test.zip", ZipArchiveMode.Read))
{
    foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in zip.Entries)
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(entry.Open()))
        {
            var result = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

You probably don't want to read in the raw zip file into a byte array first and then try to decompress it. Instead, access it through this helper method.

Note the use of `ZipArchive.Entries` to access the sub-files stored in the single zip archive; this tripped me up when first learning to use zip files.